# Trying to understand a proof where disjoint decomposition of $\mathbb R^n$ is used.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to understand what a disjoint decomposition is, specifically in the following proof of Example IV.8 (the last paragraph):

[image]

I don't understand how they got the last line of Example IV.8 from $(\dagger)$.

Comment: Another term is a partition.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}^n = X$ is the *disjoint* union of the given sets, say $A, B, C$. That is $X = A \cup B \cup C$. Nothing that is in C can be in $A$ or $B$ (sets are disjoint), so $C \subseteq (A \cup B)^c$. Also if something is not neither present in $A$ nor in $B$, it must be in $C$, as their union is $X$. So $(A \cup B)^c \subseteq C$. Together, we get $C = (A \cup B)^c$.